# Typescript: returnType based on value 'single' prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm going to try to explain this as best as I can with a simplified version of my function:

I have this function where I fetch data from a third-party API. Based on the 'single' prop the returned value will either be an a single table object or an array of table objects.

I put a generic value on table prop and single prop. But it seems like this doesn't work with how the function is set up at the moment. My goal is to explain that when single is true, it will just return an object of a table and when single is false it will be an array of table objects. What should be changed?

```
function useData<T extends TableNames, S extends boolean>({
  query: { table, select = [], filters = [], single = false, limit },
}: UseDataProps<T, S>): UseDataReturn<T, S> {
  const { data } = getData();

  return {
    data: data[table],
  };
}

interface UseDataProps<T, S> {
  query: {
    table: T;
    select?: string[];
    filters?:string[];
    single?: S;
    limit?: number;
  };
}

interface UseDataReturn<T, S> {
  data: S extends true ? Table<T> : Table<T>[];
}
```

On the single prop I currently get an error like this:

Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'S'.
'boolean' is assignable to the constraint of type 'S', but 'S' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'boolean'.

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs and see what you're seeing. Right now that code has a bunch of errors, almost all of which are related to missing declarations. Are these things something you have privately declared but not shown us? Or are they things you have imported from react? Are they needed at all to demonstrate the issue? If not then could you remove them? If you can [edit] to make it easy for others to get started, you have a better chance of getting helpful answers. Good luck!

Comment: (see prev comment) *possibly* what you're running into is [ms/TS#56315](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56315); you can't say that `false` is assignable to `S` because someone could manually specify `S` to be whatever they want.  I'd probably write `S extends boolean = false` to make `S` default to `false` and then `single = false as S` to make TS accept that `false` is a valid `S`, and ignore the unlikely possibility anyone will manually specify `S` as `true` without supplying `single`. But this is just a guess, and I won't know how to proceed until a [mre] appears in the q.